# i had to do a project on weather prediction. unable to import the dataset in jupyter

Tags: python

```
os.chdir("..")

weather_df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\weatherHistory.csv")
```

```
 File "<ipython-input-29-7f8013c3f0c4>", line 3
    weather_df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\weatherHistory.csv")
                            ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 0):

`\` is a special character, which must be escaped.
For example, `\n` specifies a new line.

So instead of `\` write `\\` in the path.
Or write an `r` in front of the quotation marks: `r""`

```py
weather_df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\weatherHistory.csv")
```

or

```py
weather_df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\weatherHistory.csv")
```